# Using PHP plugin or jQuery plugin with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, plugins, web

Can I use any standard PHP plugin or jQuery plugin (or scripts) in a website built using CodeIgniter, without making any modifications to that plugin (or in its original form)?

Please share info,
Thanks

Comment: jQuery is javascript and runs in browser and has no knowledge of framework let alone server language. Totally different environments

Comment: ok @charlietfl, it means jQuery plugins are not going to work in CodeIgniter websites?

Comment: no it means codeigniter is irrelevant.... all server languages sent html to browser... and jQuery runs in browser long afer server code is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can use library and helper for PHP and jQuery you can use library ajax for CI